# What should we name our chatroom?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Currently, it is the generic name of the site.

What should we name our chatroom?  Perhaps give your suggestions here and the popularity could be gauged by how many votes each suggestion gets.

Comment: Personally I think "The time machine" would have been perfect. However History.SE has this already. So... *Time machine 2 .. ? ..*

Answer (score 14):

[On the Shoulders of Giants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants)

Comment: The Shoulders of Giants would indeed be a neat name.

Comment: Now my [location](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque) is ambiguous!

Answer (score 11):

Archimedes Circle

(for an ancient vibe; he figured out how to find the area of a circle)

(I thought of his irrigation pump first, but there was um  a bit of an *overloaded word* issue for that one... :)

Comment: Do not disturb our circles :)

Comment: It's perhaps worth pointing out that one would have a hard time finding a historical figure who better captures the combined impact of math, science, and engineering than Archimedes. That he also quantified the circle, a universal symbol of inclusion, just adds to it nicely.

Answer (score 4):

I'll start off with a suggestion:

**Newton's Cradle**

Answer (score 1):

That might be a bit cryptic, but what about "**[the Eagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eagle_(pub))**" after the pub in which Crick announced the discovery of DNA?

Comment: very nice idea!

Comment: I'd have to agree, after having more than a few beers there...

Comment: This is a bit too cryptic for my tastes. If I knew only that the name "The Eagle" was referencing something related to the history of science, I think I'd first guess the [Apollo 11 Lunar Module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module), then perhaps the [Eagle nebula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Nebula). It could also be [the Martian Eagle crater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_(crater)). While I like the idea of using some particular location, I'd prefer something more easily recognizable by name alone.

Answer (score -2):

Dyson Sphere

(for a future vibe; sort of a culmination of where science could go. Less cozy than Archimedes Circle... :)

Comment: That would actually be a nice suggestion for [Worldbuilding](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/194/308). But I do not see how it fits here.

Comment: I agree; in fact, I would ask that folks not vote for this one. As you note, it's just the wrong place for it.