# Is there something that needs to be done when the main chatroom is frozen?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

If you look at the chat rooms [associated with HSM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=hsm.stackexchange.com) you can see that there is a room called [On the way to Damascus](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/117320/on-the-way-to-damascus). The room [On the Shoulder of Giants](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/18230/on-the-shoulders-of-giants) has [been frozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/18230/2021/1/16). (As far as I can tell, this happened now [for the first time](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=frozen&room=18230&user=-2).)

This is how the system is set up - rooms are frozen after 14 days of inactivity, but at least one room associated with the site is always kept - even if it was silent for a longer period of time.<sup>1</sup> However, it might be useful to keep open one room which is, in some sense, a general room for the site - as opposed to some room which is devoted to some specific topic.

The room which has now been frozen has, in some sense, at least a semi-official status as the "main" room for the site. It was [discussed here on meta](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-should-we-name-our-chatroom). And it is the room that was [created together with the creation of the site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/18230/2014/10/28).

On the other hand, since this room is silent most of the time, maybe it is not really needed. (And maybe if somebody needs it, they can unfreeze it using some of the [recommended methods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/frozen-rooms/info). But less experienced users are less likely to find the room which has been frozen and might not know how to unfreeze the room.)

**Question:** Should this specific room be kept alive? If somebody notices that it was frozen, what are they supposed to do?

*Note.* I could have simply notified some moderator (from this site or from another site) and ask them to unfreeze the room. But I do not have something I would need to discuss there now - so before doing that, I wanted to ask whether the room is worth keeping around at all.

<sup>1</sup>Some more details on this can be found here: [Don't freeze a chatroom soon after a mod has unfrozen it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130472#130504) and [Why is the main chat room frozen?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/343#351) I'll include also a link to my question on Meta Stack Exchange related to this topic: [Main chatroom for a SE site and chatroom pruning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226302).

Comment: General update: The chatroom was unfrozen on [2022-1-11](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60121713#60121713).