# Please help remove a spam post on the main site

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

I noticed that there is a spam answer that is lying undeleted on the main site for over 24 hours. Normally, I would try contacting a moderator in the main chatroom for some help, but since [that has been frozen for many months now](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/347/14365) I felt that Meta would be the next best option.

The spam post is an answer to this question: [Why was Évariste Galois killed?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/9/14365). I'm not sure whether linking directly to the answer somehow provides a benefit to the spammer, so I'm linking to the question just to be on the safe side. The answer is currently sitting at a score of −7, so it looks like it's accumulated plenty of spam flags already, and a few more should delete it for good.

Please help by flagging the offending answer as spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for calling attention to the spam post, and my apologies for the slow reaction. The post has now been deleted.